# oclvanitygen not compiling

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, vanitygen

I am trying to compile oclvanitygen because I have an Nvidia GTX 1080 that would most likely be helpful for this. I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried this command: `gcc oclvanitygen.o oclengine.o pattern.o util.o -o oclvanitygen -ggdb -O3 -Wall -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpcre -lcrypto -lm -lpthread -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencl.so.1`

It basically says that `libopencl.so.1` does not exist. However, I have `libnvidia-opencl.so.1`, so I try this command: `gcc oclvanitygen.o oclengine.o pattern.o util.o -o oclvanitygen -ggdb -O3 -Wall -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lpcre -lcrypto -lm -lpthread -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1`

Then it says `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1`

So I do a list of `x86_64-linux-gnu`, and there it is, clear as day. [list of x86-64-linux-gnu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T10sV.jpg)

How can I compile this correctly? Here is a picture of what happens when I run the command: [GCC Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sDCm.jpg)

I have installed the `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` package, but it does not include `libopencl.so.1`.

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you want to generate a vanity address, I suggest you use Vanitygen Plus

https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus (More up to date and features)

and to compile, run `make -f Makefile` after u clone the repo and cd into it.

Comment: Yes, but can I compile oclvanitygen from it?

Comment: I have it, but I'm still getting an error code of -1001 when I look for opencl gpus when I installed cuda 10 on ubuntu.

Comment: Vanitygen-plus is newer and more feature than legacy Vanitygen (which is ~7-8 years ago). So yes it more stable and has same feature as Vanitygen.


Also, you should also use Makefile to compile the source instead using gcc to compile it since it has all the required configuration it needed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The Subsystem tends to have some issues. It's not as mature as other solutions. Try something like MinGW, MSys or Cygwin, or cross-compile on a proper Linux virtual machine and transfer the compiled executable back to your host.